# Dhcp server on windows 2008r2 gives this error: "unable to determine the dhcp server version"

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp, netsh

Hi i have two dhcp server on my lan and each of them is running on a dc (windows 2008r2).
i'd like to manage both of the dhcp server from the command line with the netsh command by domain\administrator as user but i'm unable to do that on the remote host because it gives me this error :

```
unable to determine the dhcp server version
```

althought it works on local, i checked the firewall policy both on local and remote and they look fine.

do you have an idea on how to fix that?

thank you in advance